# Javascript remove remove key with false value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to modify an array before submitting it to an api that requires only the id's. I've generated a an array of values, however, my array contains false values depending on how the user interacts with the UI.

```
    [2: true, 3: true, 5: true]
```

However, sometimes it displays like this:

```
    [1: false, 2: true, 3: true, 5: true, 6: false]
```

How can I filter this so that it removes the false values, and also removes the values, so the ideal data would look like this:

```
    [2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: strange looking array

Comment: How are you creating that array? It looks more like an object/associative-array in the first instance.

Comment: I think array contains objects

Comment: ``[2: true, 3: true, 5: true]``
-> ``SyntaxError: Unexpected token :``
Your array is not valid JS code

Comment: It's an angular function, returning a list of checkboxes that have been checked. If the user checks and unchecks a box, it creates the value: false key/value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear what the shape of your input is because what you wrote is not valid JS syntax.

Assuming that your initial "array" is in fact a map (object), you can do this:

```
var initial =  {1: false, 2: true, 3: true, 5: true, 6: false};
var final = []; // the array that will contain the result
for (var key in initial) { // iterate through all properties
  if (initial.hasOwnProperty(key)){ // safety check against object poisoning
    if (initial[key]) { // only push true values
      final.push(+key); // + converts the key to a number. Remove it if you want string
    }
  }
}

console.log(final); // [2,3,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array and loop the old one like this and add the values which are true to the new array.

```
var old_array = [false, true, true, true, false];
var new_array = new Array();
for(i = 0; i < old_array.length; i++) {
    if (old_array[i] == true) {
        new_array.push(old_array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: 'var old_array = [1: false, 2: true, 3: true, 5: true, 6: false];' ... you cannot define an array like this, syntax error. You either create a object like this 'var old_array = {1: false, 2: true, 3: true, 5: true, 6: false};' or an array like this 'var old_array =  [false, true, true, true, false];'

Comment: Sry for bad copy-paste habits. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

So say

The

```
var arr = [false, true, false, true, true];
```

The function to remove the values

```
 function removeFalseValues(array){
    for(var i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++){
         if(array[i] == false){
              delete(array[i]);
         }
    }
    return array;
}
```

And the call

```
removeFalseValues(arr);
```

Comment: But see the OP has different array structure